# Не могу запустить Apache на Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

Отказывается запускаться Apache, вот что пишет:

```
15:08:46  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...

15:08:46  [Apache]  Status change detected: running

15:08:47  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped

15:08:47  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

15:08:47  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 

15:08:47  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another 
method.

15:08:47  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

15:08:47  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

15:08:47  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this

15:08:47  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Вот что пишет в error.log

```
[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.220403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.409403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.425403 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.425403 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.425403 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache -f conf\\httpd.conf'

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.427403 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6836

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:25.866403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6836:tid 264] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:26.064403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6836:tid 264] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:26.081403 2017] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6836:tid 264] (OS 109)Канал был закрыт.  : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:26.084403 2017] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6724:tid 252] AH00427: Parent: child process 6836 exited with status 3 -- Aborting.

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:46.560403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:46.706403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:46.722403 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:46.722403 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:46.722403 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:46.723403 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6200

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:47.136403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6200:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:47.234403 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6200:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:47.250403 2017] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6200:tid 268] (OS 109)Канал был закрыт.  : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent

[Sat Mar 11 15:08:47.253403 2017] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 5388:tid 376] AH00427: Parent: child process 6200 exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

Не знаю как пофиксить, из форума xampp понял, что это ошибка часто встречается, только не нашел ответ. Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался? Помогите:)

Comment: Апач ломится на сайт www.example.com за сертификатом... да только нет его там.
А OpenServer не устраивает?

Comment: Проблема в том, что не одна программа апаче запускать не хочет

Comment: Так может с Windows проблема?  В логах пишет, This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown.
Порт заблокирован, а может какой процесс не дает Апачу запуститься.

Comment: Так я поэтому и спрашиваю, может как-то это проверить и починить? Я сам уже неделю роюсь и пытаюсь сделать, не смог.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй MAMP. Вроде он выпендриваться не должен.
https://www.mamp.info/en/

По опыту знаю, что в настройки Apache лучше не лезть.
Если у тебя работает скайп, то выключи его - он мешает работе как Денвера, XAMPP'а, OpenSever и прочих.

Comment: Я все уже перепробовал, никакой не запускается. В скайпе настройки портов менял, но скайп я и так не запускаю.

Comment: А просматривал, какие программы занимают 80 и 3306 порт? Либо программы либо процессы. Если да то попробуй их убить и запусти локалхост.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Стой, стой, есть еще такая штука, как встроенный в систему MySQL и модуль Apache. Если используешь сторонние программ для локального сервера, то необходимо выключить встроенные модули, чтобы они не конфликтовали.

Comment: А я должен знать, какие программы используют локальный сервер?:D А то я понятия не имею.
По поводу портов, то мне что-то не показывает порт 80 вообще, хз почему.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx                  Прочитай. Там параметр PID (Port ID) и есть название порта.

Comment: Вот глянь: может поможет                                http://zametkinapolyah.ru/servera-i-protokoly/chto-takoe-http-server-apache-ustanovka-veb-servera-apache-2-4-na-windows-gde-skachat-apache-2-4-dlya-windows.html#_Apache__HTTP_Apache_Windows                          И обрати вниманае на работу с файлом httpd.conf там имя сервера (Вбей в блокноте в поиск CTRL+ F вот это "ServerName") и если ServerName закоментирован (# в начале строки), то убери  # и напиши: ServerName localhost:80

Comment: Потому, что как ты видишь у тебя в ошибке написано www.example.com а надо, чтобы было http://localhost

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Панель управления</kbd> -> <kbd>Администрирование</kbd> -> <kbd>Диспетчер служб IIS</kbd> -> <kbd>Сайты</kbd> Выделить все и справа нажать <kbd>Остановить</kbd>

Comment: Это может быть одной из причин, обычно после обновления до Windows 10. А так нужно просто посмотреть чем занят выделенный под apache порт